# Why the given below URL is not opening in Webview

Tags: java, android

I want to open the following URL in my Webview but it's not working

URL:- https://ebiz.licindia.in/D2CPM/#DirectPay

**My webView**

```
mywebview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
WebSettings webSettings=mywebview.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
valfromact1=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Value");
mywebview.loadUrl(valfromact1);
mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
mywebview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
mywebview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
mywebview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
mywebview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
mywebview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_INSET);
mywebview.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
mywebview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
mywebview.getCertificate();
```

Comment: Does it gives any error ?

Comment: Did you put internet permission?

Comment: have you added internet permission in manifest ?

Comment: remove every `get*` function you call and check if it works. If it does, then re-add every `get*` function until it stops working.

Comment: Please check that you have the updated Version of `WebView`. as you can see here https://imgur.com/a/76cQ6ys.   
and I Have tried in my Emulator and devices it is working perfectly. remove all the get first then try.

Comment: @Satyajit Kairi have you got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

webview_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/help_webview"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:scrollbars="none"
/>
```

In Activity file

```
webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.help_webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("https://ebiz.licindia.in/D2CPM/#DirectPay");
```

make sure that the INTERNET permission is enabled in Manifest file.

Hope this will help you. Thank you